# Транслитерация, поиск по БД, в которых в тексте могут присутствовать как английские так и русские буквы

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть автоматический выключатель, 2х полюсный, называется он "Модульный автоматический выключатель iC60N 2p 63A B 230AC" и есть поисковик. Когда в поисковике я пишу запрос 2р(пэ английское) поисковик его находит, когда 2р(эр русское) нет.
Сам запрос к БД выглядит так

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name` LIKE '%2p 63A%' OR `art` LIKE '%2p 63A%' OR `description` LIKE '%2p 63A%' ORDER BY `art`
```

Как можно сделать так, чтоб независимо от того какую букву пользователь применит (русскую или английскую) запрос пробежался и в кириллице и в латинице по базе? Или подскажите куда нужно копать. Существуют наименования и технические характеристики в которых все латинские буквы совпадают с кириллическими, например переменный ток 63А (ампера) или 63А (ampers). Если что в PHP новичок.
Код поисковика

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $wordin = $_POST['search'];
    $word = (string)$wordin;
    $a = "SELECT * FROM 'product' WHERE 'name' LIKE '%";
    $b = "%' OR 'art' LIKE '%";
    $c = "%' OR 'description' LIKE '%";
    $h = "%' ORDER BY 'art'";
    $sql = $a.$word.$b.$word.$c.$word.$h;
    echo $sql;
    // Получаем результаты
    $row =  mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $count_row = 0;
    foreach ($row as $line){
                $count_row = $count_row + 1;
    };
    if($count_row !== 0) {
        echo '<h1>Результат поиска<h1>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($row as $r){
                    echo '<li><a href="product.php?id='.$r['id'].'">'.$r['name'].'</a></li>';                   
        };
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Ничего не найдено<h1>';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Вариантов минимум два. Первый - нормализовать как данные, так и критерий, приведя их к одному и тому же виду (преобразовав кириллицу в латиницу или наоборот). Второй - создать, зарегистрировать и использовать collation, в котором такие символы неразличимы. PS. первое - проще в реализации. PPS. Это не транслитерация.

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать.

Comment: 3. писать дебильный запрос вида `WHERE name LIKE '%2р 63A%' OR name LIKE '%2p 63A%'`

Comment: Но сначала надо конечно защитить этот код от инъекций

Comment: // никогда не доверяйте входящим данным! Фильтруйте всё!
    $wordin = $_POST['search'];     $word = (string)$wordin; кусок поисковика - как я понял защита от инъекций. К сожалению я не большой знаток ПХП что и написал сверху, у меня немного другая профессия, но пытаюсь развиваться сам по вечерам, так что код может и дебильненький, уж извините.